# how to get the difference of 2 times in oracle (only times not date)

Tags: oracle

I have given 2 times of a day ant told to find the difference between them in minute.

I know how to get the difference between 2 date times, but know how to get the difference between 2 times.

For instance I have time 10:00 AM and another time 1:00 PM the difference is 180 minutes .then 10:00 AM to 10:10 AM 10 minutes difference.
Can anyone give me a function where I will send 2 parameters like from time and to time and result will return the minutes?

Or if it is possible to give me anything by what i can find the difference between those times without the date ?

Comment: Are you given the times as `VARCHAR2` values in a particular format, or `DATE` values that may or may not be on the same day and you want to ignore the date part?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the time in VARCHAR to a DATE type. By default, the 1st day of the current month will be applied to the date part.
Once you have this, its simple subtraction of dates and multiplying by 24*60 to get the minutes.

```
(to_date(to_time,'hh12:mi AM') - to_date(from_time,'hh12:mi AM')) * 24 * 60
```

Example:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/32100)

```
with x(y,z) as (
  select '10:00 AM', '1:00 PM' from dual
  )
select y, z,
to_date(y,'hh12:mi AM'),
to_date(z,'hh12:mi AM'),
to_date(z,'hh12:mi AM') - to_date(y,'hh12:mi AM'),
(to_date(z,'hh12:mi AM') - to_date(y,'hh12:mi AM')) * 24 * 60
from x

|        Y |       Z |      TO_DATE(Y,'HH12:MIAM') |      TO_DATE(Z,'HH12:MIAM') | TO_DATE(Z,'HH12:MIAM')-TO_DATE(Y,'HH12:MIAM') | (TO_DATE(Z,'HH12:MIAM')-TO_DATE(Y,'HH12:MIAM'))*24*60 |
|----------|---------|-----------------------------|-----------------------------|-----------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------|
| 10:00 AM | 1:00 PM | July, 01 2014 10:00:00+0000 | July, 01 2014 13:00:00+0000 |                                         0.125 |                                                   180 |
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `to_char` and `to_date` given by Eat A Peach  is one possibility, the other one is using `trunc`.

Example:

```
select (firstdate-trunc(firstdate))-(seconddate-trunc(seconddate))
  from sometable;
```

The result is in days, so you have to multiply it with 1440 to get it in minutes.